# ExpandableListView and SimpleCursorTreeAdapter

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, simplecursortreeadapter

I want to use an `ExpandableListView` backed with a `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter`. So far, I can't get anything on my screen.

To do this, I create a class of my own derived from the `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter` class. In this class, I override the `getChildrenCursor` to retrieve the children of the group specified in the parameters list. I create an instance of this class with an `SQLiteCursor` for the source of data and my views are simple `TextView`s, both for the group and the children. My cursor has some data (2 rows in my example), and I get no error message, but the `ExpandableListView` doesn't display anything on the screen.

I can add that, with a class derived from the `BaseExpandableListAdapter`, I have been able to see my data.

Am I missing something? Is there a place where I could find a code sample using the `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter` class in conjunction with the `ExpandableListView` class?

Comment: How exactly did you extended the `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter`?

Comment: In the "getChildrrenCursor" function, I do a query to get a "Cursor" which contains the children of the group passed as a parameter.